# Can I combine this Dockpanel into a user control or custom control?

Tags: wpf, xaml, controls, scrollviewer, tabitem

I have the following XAML inside a `<TabItem>`:

```
<ScrollViewer ....>
    <Border ....>
        <DockPanel ...>
        ....
        </DockPanel>
    </Border>
</ScrollViewer>
```

This same XAML is going to repeated multiple times. I'm wondering if it would be easier to create some type of `UserControl` or `custom control` (*not sure user control will work*).  Then, if I need to change a setting on one of those 3 it would cascade to all `TabItems` that contain the `ScrollViewer/Border/DockPanel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the abouve XAML code into a UserControl for instance, but you need to know that each time you use the user control, a diferent instace will be created. So if you want update all instaces you need to make a binding to a common INotifyPropertyChanged class property.

Hope this could helps...

Comment: One thing I've struggled with in WPF is Panels and UserControls.  When I put a panel in a user control and then try and use that UserControl in MainWindow.xaml, I can't have more than one child to the user control because content can only be set once.

Comment: In WPF are two main type of controls: items controls and content controls, items controls can have several children instead content control only have one. Window is a ContentControl, so you need to set an items control in the Window.Content property, also you can set a Panel like a grid, stack panel, wrap panel, or dock panel to set sever items into a window.

Comment: I've created a UserControl with my DockPanel.  Could you point me to an example of what you are talking about?

Comment: The answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094486/adding-children-to-usercontrol) worked great.